# Auto-captioning turned on by default on Youtube

Tags: youtube, closed-captions

I have a youtube vido for which youtube provided auto captioning, I want to embed the video on my blog but i want to have auto captioning turned on by default. **&cc_load_policy=1** didn't work for me.

Comment: Does the video you are linking to actually have captions?  It seems to [work for me](http://jsfiddle.net/jADC6/).

Comment: Yes These are automatic captioning provided by Youtube. the video i am trying to post is as bellows
http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=Mz9uB0CAvWM

Comment: My guess would be that the `cc_load_policy` is only for non-generated captions. If you're not the owner of the video, you may be out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Add a tag to the video containing the following:
yt:cc=on

Comment: didnt work, https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEOID?cc_load_policy=1&cc_lang_pref=en&autohide=1&controls=1&loop=0&rel=0&fs=1&wmode=opaque&showinfo=1&modestbranding=1&iv_load_policy=1&theme=light&color=red&playsinline=0&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2F2017.public.onecnc.proj&widgetid=1&yt:cc=on